# Android Media Player : How to Play Video from separated file

Tags: java, android, download, media-player

I'm Trying to play a secure video that can't copy it. I searched and find some (exoplayer but didn't know how decrypt video then play) . And now i have an idea but does not know how to do it . i want to download some critical information about video in a file and the rest in other file, then play video when need it without delay and I do not want to write the complete file in another file then play .
Thanks

Comment: first check the documentation or whatever about the algorithm the video was encrypted with

Comment: hi . it is AES 128 . **About exoplayer i didnt understand how play encrypted video** . and **this question is about a simple mp4 file** .  thanks .

Comment: didnt understand . if any1 could give me some example .